# How to add data to res.partner fields for mlutiple companies via API

Tags: odoo, erp

I'm trying to add account payable and receivable fields for a partner in Odoo via API. However, they are only being applied to the default company. I hope the following images clarify.

1. How it appears for our default company :

[image]

2. How it appears for the other company :

[image]

I'm creating a partner as follows :

```
user_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'create', [{'name': name,'email':email,'company_id': odoo_company_id,'property_account_payable_id':account_payable_id,'property_account_receivable_id':account_receivables_id,'property_product_pricelist':pricelist_id}])
```

Any idea how this can be done ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: payable and receivable should be belongs the company you are passing. each company have different chart of accounts

Comment: @VishnuVaNnErI I noticed that when i changed the admins default company to the other one it worked . Is there a way to assign it or bypass it via the APIs ?

Comment: Try to call account.account based on the company you are going to  access then create customer

Comment: @VishnuVaNnErI How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Those are properties and values are stored in `ir.property` objects. You probably have to write those entries for each company.

Remember that accounts are company-depending objects as well, so you cannot use same `account.account` object to every company. They are different objects with different ids in database even if accounts may have same code and name and you cannot see any difference on user interface.

You can also define default property for each company, if that is what you want. It can be done through GUI.